# AdMob with google.com example

Tags: android, admob

I published my app ten days ago and now I got this message. I don't know how to solve this with the information in the internet and stackoverflow.

> We have identified a potential advertising ID policy violation with your app(s). Please review the flagged app(s) listed in your All Applications page for details.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sInstance = this;

            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-****************/**********");
            requestNewInterstitial();
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    requestNewInterstitial();
                }
            });
            startAd();
        }    

void showAd() {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        mLastAd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        if (MyApplication.getInstance().isAdEnabled()) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();

            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }

    private void startAd() {
        if (MyApplication.getInstance().isAdEnabled()) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        showAd();
                    } else {
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                    }

                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    }
```

I compile this:

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

and my Manifest is the same like

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration

That is my first app and the first with AdMob using for generate just some euros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will receive this warning if you use persistent ID other than the advertising ID.

From Google:

> As a reminder, please note that starting 1 August 2014, new apps and app updates distributed through Google Play must use the advertising ID in lieu of any other persistent identifiers for any advertising purposes, on devices that support the advertising ID.

Checkout this link - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248

Comment: i don't get it :-( is it wrong to use my "ca-app-pub-****************/**********" from the created admob initial ad?

Comment: Is it allowed to click on my own ads? Should I implement a .addTestDevice() for my private smartphone? Because I clicked on a ad in the past.

Comment: Always use addTestDevice  when using your own device.

Comment: Your account will be suspended if you click on your own ads

Comment: ok thank, i added my own device as addTestDevice and the message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost certainly received the policy violation warning because you are showing the interstitial at an arbitrary point in your app (You are essentially showing it as soon as the ad has been loaded which will be while the user is actually performing an action) instead of at a natural break point.

Admob have said consistently said **not** to do this.

Comment: i have a splash screen and every 5 minutes a user joins the mainActivity is appears, isn't that a good way?

Comment: No, that would be violating policy (for the reasons specified above) and will get your account banned.

Comment: how should I do that? I just want to show it one time at the start.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. Interstitias are not a good fit for all apps. If you don't have a natural break popint at the start (or other point) in your app, then you are probably better using banner ads.